# Slow work of yield-generator using PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yield

In article's page of my forum, program have to show up all article's comments. I use function-iterator that returns one entry from database (using PDO methods) after each iteration in foreach-cycle. It actually works and all required comments become visible. But article's page loads toooo slow, about 15 seconds. Also in console I see the Warning:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received. article.php:1

The questions are: 
1. Why it works so slow & how to fix it? 
2. Can the problem be caused by my weak laptop? I run all scripts on my localhost.

```php
<?php
function getComment($article_id, $parent) {
    if ($parent == 0) {
        $comments = getPDO()->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id = :article_id ORDER BY put_date DESC");
        $comments->execute([
            "article_id" => $article_id
        ]);
    }
    else {
        $comments = getPDO()->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id = :article_id AND parent = :parent ORDER BY put_date ASC");
        $comments->execute([
            "article_id" => $article_id,
            "parent" => $parent
        ]);
    }
    while ($line = $comments->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        yield $line;
        if(entryExists(getPDO(), $line["id"], "parent", "comments")) getComment(false, $line["id"]);
    }
}
?>

<!-- some html... -->
<div class="comments_block">
    <? foreach (getComment($_GET["id"], 0) as $line) { ?>
        <div class="comment">
            <!-- there is all stuff that uses info from $line -->
        </div>
    <? } ?>
</div>
<!-- some html... -->
```

entryExists() is the function that check existing of an entry; 
getPDO() just returns a PDO-link to the database

Comment: maybe you should consider pagination? or avoid n+1 queries, or better, both

Comment: by the way, your `->prepare` don't make sense since you still directly inject your variables in the actual statement, nothing is really bound, so much for "prepared" statements

Comment: @Ghost yes, i tried to limit the query, but it didn't work. About 'prepare': yes, it's really strange one ':D Now i've fixed it, but it still doesn't work as i expect